# Instalar JDK 8, 9 ou 10 no Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, jdk

Alguém sabe uma outra forma de instalar o java no ubuntu 18.04.

Tentei o java 8 e 10 e deu esses erros:

"O pacote oracle-java10-installer não está disponível, mas é referenciado por outro pacote.
Isto pode significar que o pacote está faltando, ficou obsoleto ou
está disponível somente a partir de outra fonte

E: O pacote 'oracle-java10-installer' não tem candidato para instalação"

"O pacote oracle-java8-installer não está disponível, mas é referenciado por outro pacote.
Isto pode significar que o pacote está faltando, ficou obsoleto ou
está disponível somente a partir de outra fonte"

Comment: Vai no seu terminal e digita: sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Comment: Dá pra instalar o default-jdk que é o OpenJDK. Não resolve? Acredito que, hoje em dia, pra instalar ferramentas do Oracle, só criando uma conta no site da Oracle e baixando direto deles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instala o Java 8 do Oracle**

```bsh
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

**Verificar a versão instalada**

deixe a versão 8 como padrão

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

```bsh
$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

**Configurar as variáveis de ambientes**

```bsh
cat >> /etc/environment <<EOL
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
EOL
```

**Opção alternativa com openJDK**

```bsh
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma e ocorreu os erros que eu disse

Comment: vc tentou dar um `sudo apt update` antes de fazer o `sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer`?

Comment: sim, tentei mas tb n deu certo

Comment: @Leandro tenta a opção alternativa com openJDK

Comment: voce sabe se há muita diferença entre o jdk da oracle e o openjdk?

Comment: não tem muita diferença, eu sempre usei o openJDK e nunca deu problema, desenvolvo pra android usando esse java instalado

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra opção seria usar a versão empacotada com o Ubuntu.
Abra o terminal e atualize o índice de pacotes:

```
sudo apt update
```

Outro passo indispensável seria verificar se o Java já está instalado, para verificar use:

```
java -version
```

Se o Java não estiver instalado será possível obter a mensagem com algo similar a *"Command 'java' not found"*
Sendo assim iremos verificar/instalar o Java Runtime Environment(JRE), lembrando que o JRE permite que você execute quase todos os softwares Java.
É possível verificar a instalação do JRE a partir do seguinte comando no terminal:

```
java -version
```

Se o resultado for igual ou similar à:

```
Output
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Então você já possui o JRE instalado, caso contrário, utilize o comando a seguir para instalar o JRE padrão, que instalará o JRE do OpenJDK:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Você também pode precisar do Java Development Kit(JDK) além do JRE para compilar e executar alguns softwares específicos baseados no Java. Para instalar o JDK, execute o seguinte comando, que também instalará o JRE:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

É possível verificar se o JDK está instalado verificando a versão do javac, o compilador do Java:

```
javac -version
```

Aonde o terminal retornará o seguinte resultado:

```
Output
javac 11.0.7
```